# SailsJs 10 rc 9 connect-redis error

Tags: session, redis, sails.js

I've upgraded my project to use the latest sailsJs 10.0-rc9.
After running sails lift, it said I should install and use connect-redis@1.4.5 (for sessions).
I installed as required.

However, immediately after login and receiving a session, the server crashes and I get this:

```
connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method
connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method

/home/robert/work/optiwise/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:525
            throw err;
                  ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I would rather not mess with the code of a third party module. Anyone know why this is actually happening?

My session setup is below, if it makes a difference:

```
module.exports.session = {

        secret: '38fc8ad5342e5e6555508c01645d5528',

        // Set the session cookie expire time
        // The maxAge is set by milliseconds, the example below is for 24 hours
        //
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        },


        adapter: 'redis',        

        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6666
}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, however, I'm using MongoDB as storage...

Comment: Go same thing, but mine crashes on `node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:1484`. I dont think this is a redis or a loDash issue. If I prevent the server from connecting to the sails socket, it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 3):

This bug already fixed at edge version of sails. For install it just execute:

`npm install sails@git://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue. Mine was with MongoDB as session storage